# True or false with justification

Tags: calculus

State whether the following is true or false with justification:

If a function $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $[0,1]$ and $f(1)=1$ and $f(0)=0$ then there exists $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $$f'(c)f(c)=\frac12$$

Comment: Hint:  look for a convenient function with derivative $f'(x)f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x):= \frac{1}{2}f(x)^2$. Then $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1/2$. Now proceed with the Mean Value Theorem.